# Column layout of RDLC Report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, reportviewer, rdlc

I am creating an RDLC report in Visual Studio 2013.

I design the report in VS, and create a datasheet to base the report on, then create a strongly type list at runtime and generate the report.

My report currently looks like this , basically for a date range (dd/mm) I show time entries.

[image]

However now the users want the report to go across like this:

[image]

Should I hardcode the date columns and bring back a 'flat' record set with a time for each date in date range, or is there a way in RDLC reports to turn a recordset like the one I have into column headers ? Sorry my reporting skills are very basic.

Here is my c# for generating the report if that helps, but my code is fine and it's more about how to layout the report that is the issue here ?

```
var reportData = this.GetEmployeeReportData(input);

///Create a reporting datasource for our report
ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("EmployeeMonthlyDS", reportData);

// Setup the report viewer object and get the array of bytes
ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = path;
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rd); // Add datasource here

byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
fileName = "Test" + id;

Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = mimeType;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "." + extension);
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes); // create the file
Response.Flush(); // send it to the client to download
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement calls for Matrix report. The idea is that your date values will be placed in the header of dynamic columns and projects into row headers. Here is the [explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms251709(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: InitKnit, is there a limit as to the number of columns that will be generated ? I am only getting 4 columns for 4 dates the rest although returned in the record set do not show up in the matxi table?

Comment: No, there is no limit. Check your grouping. It's hard to say what could go wrong without seeing the data, but try to make it real simple at the beginning, just add column grouping by Date and nothing else.

Comment: Ah i had it grouped on the time instead of the date. Thanks